# How to know if USB hub receives enough power to power all my applicants/devices(used bandwidth)?

Tags: windows, usb, power-supply, power, usb-3

I have USB type c that connects these devices: (1) 2 TB SSD (2) Ethernet network (3) Mouse (4)Keyboard (5)Aux speakers.
I was wondering if the hub receives enough power or not from a single type c port.

Comment: Yes, it should. Are you trying to solve an issue? If so please describe it. If everything works then obviously it has enough power.

Comment: Everything works. Oh so it is my OCD again haha. I wanted to make sure everything is working fine.